# Auto-clicking a survey button via Javascript embedded into XML

Tags: javascript, xml, survey

This is my first time using this site. I am using the survey platform Decipher (by FocusVision). The goal is to show randomized pairs of images, which the respondent has to click on one within 3 seconds. If they do not, the survey automatically advances to the next pairing.

The platform uses XML, but allows you to put in Javascript to further customize.

Here is what I have so far:

```html
<style label="disable_continue" arg:timeout="3" mode="after" name="survey.respview.footer" with="q1" wrap="ready"><![CDATA[
var b = $ ("#btn_continue, #btn_finish");
      b.disable();
      setTimeout(function() { b.enable()} , $(timeout)*1000);
]]></style>   


<radio 
  label="q1"
  optional="1">
  <title>New Single Select Question</title>
  <comment>Select one</comment>
  <row label="r1">A</row>
  <row label="r2">B</row>
</radio>
```

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to auto-click the continue / finish buttons after they are enabled after the 3 second delay. I know this might be a very specific question, but any advice would be appreciated. If you need more info, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `.click()` on the button using a jQuery selector.

Like this:

`$(#btn_continue).click();`

Adding this after you enable the button in the timeout callback will cause it to be immediately clicked.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the platform tech, we figured out that instead of a .click() function, it needed to be a postIt() function. This automatically advanced the page after the continue button was enabled after a 3 second delay.

```html
<style label="disable_continue" arg:timeout="3" mode="after" name="survey.respview.footer" with="q1, q2" wrap="ready">
  <![CDATA[ var b=$ ("#btn_continue, #btn_finish");
  b.disable();
  setTimeout(function() {
    b.enable();
    postIt();
  }
  
  , $(timeout)*1000);
  ]]>
</style>
```